# I am writing a code for palindrome for integer, Why are my strings not comparing to be equal even when they are the same

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

1.Palindrome code using strings

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        string num=to_string(n);
        string rev;
        //Reversed the string using for loop
        for(int i=num.length();i>=0;i--)
        {
            rev+=num[i];
        }
        //Checking the strings if they are same
        cout<<num<<" "<<rev<<endl;

        if(num.compare(rev)==0)
            cout<<"wins";
        else 
            cout<<"loses";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2.Output for n=101

101 101
loses

I tried to string method on a separate integer and compare it with other string and it worked.
I don't understand why is the compare method not returning 0.

Comment: The problem is not the comparison `num.length()` is the wrong starting position. You are 1 past the end of the string.

Comment: FYI -- You don't need to use strings for this at all, and instead work purely with integer using modulus, division/multiplication and addition.  A simple loop that reconstructs the number and then checks for equality is all you need.   As a matter of fact, doing things that way would result in a much faster (in terms of runtime) solution.

Comment: But it's so much simpler to `string rev = num; std::reverse(rev);` Careful with numbers ending in 0 though. Is 1230 and 0321 palindrom?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `std::cin >> n;` reads text from the console and converts it to an integer value; `std::string num = std::to_string(n);` undoes that conversion. Just skip the middleman: `std::string num; std::cin >> num;`.

Answer (score 3):

You access `num` out of bounds since `i = num.length()` points at one character passed the last character in the string. It therefore access the terminating `\0` character and that's the first character you'll copy and that's why the strings won't match.

Possible correction:

```
for(size_t i = num.length(); i--;) {
    rev += num[i];
}
```

An alternative, less error prone, solution would be to create `rev` by using reverse iterators from `num`:

```
std::string rev(num.rbegin(), num.rend());
```

Comment: I used for(int i=num.length-1;i>=0;i++).  It worked. Thank you

Comment: @AneesPatel You are welcome! Note: `num.length() - 1` works since you use an `int` (instead of the proper `size_t` which is unsigned). If you'd used an unsigned variable, starting with `length()-1` would be dangerous in cases where `length()` may be `0`.

Comment: @AneesPatel ... and since you're new here, welcome! You may also want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `some_string[some_string.length()]` is ok (since C++11), its even writeable, you just may not assign anything else than `\0`. I don't think there is UB

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've heard both. UB and not UB and I can understand both. I've also heard that you're not even allowed to write `\0` there. I don't know what optimizations that could break if the compiler is allowed to assume that noone accesses `[num.length()]` or writes to it via `data()` (where accessing it _is_ ok). I can remove the sentense if you are sure enough though :-)

Comment: it changed from UB to not UB in C++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Updated (and that even said that assigning `\0` is ok). Nice to get that cleared up. :-)